# retrieving the current user data from firestore and use it in another query

Tags: java, android

I have two users admin and faculty. admin user can add and retrieve faculty data. database format for admin is[admin database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBOTJ.png) and faculty database is[faculty database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9cd4.png).Basically I want admin access faculty data of its department.example-The admin which have MCA department then he can only access faculty data of MCA department only.

```
public class userfaculty extends Fragment {
FirebaseFirestore fStore;
private FirebaseAuth fAuth;
RecyclerView mFirestoreList;
FirestorePagingAdapter adapter;
String admindept,adminid;
Query query;

private UserfacultyViewModel mViewModel;

public static userfaculty newInstance() {
    return new userfaculty();
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fabuserfaculty);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), AdminAddUserFaculty.class));
        }
    });
    fStore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    fAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirestoreList=view.findViewById(R.id.RVuserfaculty);
    //get current user department
    adminid=fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    fStore.collection("Admin").document(adminid).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            admindept= documentSnapshot.getString("Department");
            Log.i("Admindept",admindept);
        }
    });
```

'here I want to use retrieved current user department for accessing data'

```
    //divider decoration
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration=new 
    DividerItemDecoration(getContext(),DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.recyclerview_divider));
    mFirestoreList.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

    //Query
    query = fStore.collection("Faculty").doument("admindept").collection("Teachers");

    PagedList.Config config=new PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(10)
            .setPageSize(3)
            .build();
    //RecyclerOptions
    FirestorePagingOptions<FacultyModelA> options=new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<FacultyModelA>()
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .setQuery(query, config, new SnapshotParser<FacultyModelA>() {
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public FacultyModelA parseSnapshot(@NonNull DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
                    FacultyModelA facultyModelA=snapshot.toObject(FacultyModelA.class);
                    return facultyModelA;
                }
            })
            .build();

    adapter=new FirestorePagingAdapter<FacultyModelA, FacultyViewHolder>(options) {

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public FacultyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_single_admin_faculty,parent,false);
            return new FacultyViewHolder(v);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FacultyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull FacultyModelA model) {
            holder.list_name.setText(model.getName());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onLoadingStateChanged(@NonNull LoadingState state) {
            super.onLoadingStateChanged(state);
            switch (state){

                case LOADING_INITIAL:
                    Log.d("PAGING_LOG","All inintial data");
                    break;
                case LOADING_MORE:
                    Log.d("PAGING_LOG","All next page");
                    break;
                case FINISHED:
                    Log.d("PAGING_LOG","All data loaded");
                    break;
                case ERROR:
                    Log.d("PAGING_LOG","Error Loading Data");
                    break;
                case LOADED:
                    Log.d("PAGING_LOG","Total Item Loaded: "+getItemCount());
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    mFirestoreList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mFirestoreList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    mFirestoreList.setAdapter(adapter);

}
class FacultyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView list_name;

    public FacultyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        list_name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_fname);

    }
}

}
```

'But at this line, I got a null pointer Exception'

```
    query = fStore.collection("Faculty").doument(admindept).collection("Teachers");
```

What changes should I do...Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check my answer which I'll post separately. You've given enough information in your question, but I'd suggest to be more careful regarding proper use of English and punctuation, as many people would simply ignore a badly written question. You even have a typo in the code - "doument".

Comment: Indeed, you could use an IDE that detects typo, or read lines with errors with attention, see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

Answer (score 0):

Your document name in code is "admindept" but in the screenshot it's "MCA". Fix that and you may get it to work.